# dependency parsing (bracket format) - spanish - using nltk and stanford-nlp tag

Tags: python, nltk, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

I am trying to parse a plain text corpus of Spanish to get a result like SNLI corpus (used for entailment), I´ve ttached an extract of snli corpus below.

The church has cracks in the ceiling.
( ( The church ) ( ( has ( cracks ( in ( the ceiling ) ) ) ) . ) )
(ROOT (S (NP (DT The) (NN church)) (VP (VBZ has) (NP (NP (NNS cracks)) (PP (IN in) (NP (DT the) (NN ceiling))))) (. .)))

I tried the following code but the output was not good at all.

```html
from nltk import Tree
from functools import reduce
from nltk.parse.corenlp import CoreNLPParser

def binarize(tree):
    """
    Recursively turn a tree into a binary tree.
    """
    if isinstance(tree, str):
        return tree
    elif len(tree) == 1:
        return binarize(tree[0])
    else:
        label = tree.label()
        return reduce(lambda x, y: Tree(label, (binarize(x), binarize(y))), tree)
    
parser = CoreNLPParser(url='http://localhost:9002')
#parse, = parser.raw_parse('you could say that they regularly catch a shower, which adds to their exhilaration and joie de vivre')
parse, = parser.raw_parse('si idioma no es elegido entonces elegir español por defecto.')
print(parse)
t = parse
bt = binarize(t)
print(bt)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please can you review the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide?
Your question is not currently in a form that will get much of a response.

Specifically you should edit your question to include the steps that you have tried so far and the problems you got with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My output is produced using the `stanford-spanish-corenlp-2017-06-09-models.jar` which can be downloaded here: https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml#Download

For some reason, using newer versions of the `models.jar` file create different results.

Make sure and put the Spanish `.jar` into the folder with the rest of Stanford Core NLP (I used the latest `2018-10-05`).

Then, when you start the Stanford Core NLP server, make sure and start it in Spanish:

```
 java -mx3g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -serverProperties StanfordCoreNLP-spanish.properties -port 9000 -timeout 15000
```

Note that the Spanish instance of the `CoreNLPTagger` uses a different tag set which is detailed on the [Spanish FAQ](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/spanish-faq.shtml) page.

```
from nltk.parse.corenlp import CoreNLPParser

parser = CoreNLPParser(url='http://localhost:9000')

parsed = parser.raw_parse('si idioma no es elegido entonces elegir español por defecto.')

for node in parsed:
    print(node)
```

Example output below:

```
(ROOT
  (sentence
    (S
      (S
        (conj (cs si))
        (sn (grup.nom (nc0s000 idioma)))
        (neg (rn no))
        (grup.verb (vsip000 es)))
      (S (participi (aq0000 elegido))))
    (S
      (sadv (grup.adv (rg entonces)))
      (S
        (infinitiu (vmn0000 elegir))
        (s.a (grup.a (aq0000 español)))
        (sp (prep (sp000 por)) (sn (grup.nom (nc0s000 defecto))))))
    (fp .)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Would you please tell me how you configured out your Spanish server since I followed Stanford tutorial and I can´t get your output format. I thank your answer.

Comment: @Maria You need to first download the `stanford-spanish-corenlp-20xx-xx-xx-models.jar` from the link I provided in the answer. 

Then you need to put that `stanford-spanish-corenlp-20xx-xx-xx-models.jar` file into the `stanford-core-full` folder (wherever that is on your computer) and then type the command listed in the answer above to start the server.

Comment: Thank you @matt. I am writing below to explain better.

Comment: Of course, @Maria! Let's figure this out! Using the same `models.jar` file as me ought to produce the results in my response.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your kind feedback. I tried your way for getting the output but it´s using UD tagsets and does nothing:

```html
(ROOT
  (sentence
    (sn
      (grup.nom
        (SCONJ si)
        (NOUN idioma)
        (NOUN no)
        (AUX es)
        (VERB elegido)
        (ADV entonces)
        (VERB elegir)
        (ADJ español)
        (ADP por)
        (NOUN defecto)))
    (PUNCT .)))
```

What I see is that I need to get connected to [Stanford parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp) (Stanford CoreNLP 3.7.0, updated 2016-09-12) (Spanish model) and not [this page](http://corenlp.run/) (Stanford CoreNLP 3.9.1, updated 2018/04/05). The following parsed example is from Stanford parser demo page which I am looking for getting the exact output:

```html
(ROOT
  (sentence
    (sadv
      (grup.adv (rg si)))
    (sn
      (grup.nom (nc0s000 idioma)))
    (neg (rn no))
    (grup.verb (vsip000 es) (vmp0000 elegido))
    (S
      (sadv
        (grup.adv (rg entonces)))
      (S
        (infinitiu (vmn0000 elegir))
        (s.a
          (grup.a (aq0000 español)))
        (sp
          (prep (sp000 por))
          (sn
            (grup.nom (nc0s000 defecto))))))
    (fp .)))
```

Which is accurate and perfectly done with tagsets used in Ancora tagsets which you also mentioned above. I tried to follow using the same parser (Parser: spanishPCFG.ser.gz) but I had this result which is not the same format for SNLI corpus (bracket format) and it has some utf8 code problem ('ñ' in the word 'español' hasn´t been recognized):

```html
mark(elegido-5, si-1)
nsubj(elegido-5, idioma-2)
neg(elegido-5, no-3)
cop(elegido-5, es-4)
root(ROOT-0, elegido-5)
mark(elegir-7, entonces-6)
advcl(elegido-5, elegir-7)
det(.-12, espa-8)
appos(espa-8, ol-9)
case(defecto-11, por-10)
nmod(ol-9, defecto-11)
punct(elegir-7, .-12)
```

I do not have any idea how to get the result I want.